# What standard references discuss the differences between hypothesis testing, estimation and prediction?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, predictive-models, references

I am trying to understand the ramifications of this three-way distinction, particularly when it comes to model building. Could someone point me at the standard references on the subject?

Comment: (1) Note to close-voters: I actually think this question is clear enough, voted to leave open and upvoted - though there may not be an answer; my impression is that most people are interested in *either* hypothesis testing *or* prediction. (Time series modelers sometimes test ARIMA coefficients, but even that is usually only a means to the end of forecasting.) (2) I would typically switch the order of estimation and hypothesis testing.

Comment: @StephanKolassa (2) is cryptic!  Is it just convention?

Comment: No, just aesthetic. Typically, you would estimate first, then test the estimates. What would you test before you had estimated anything? (I may have been unclear: I was referring to the title of your question.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa That makes sense. I was following the order in Frank Harrell's RMS. (Title of Section 1.1).

Comment: A good text aimed at people seriously interested in statistics -- say, a first post-intro course at the college level -- will cover all these distinctions.  So, look at our threads concerning such references.

Comment: @whuber I was looking for something more in-depth, and I just found it -- see the answer.

Comment: "more in-depth" than what, precisely?  Many of the standard and classic texts cover these topics in greater depth than anyone needs except a theoretical researcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reference is [Shmueli 2010. To Explain or to Predict?](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ealdous/157/Papers/shmueli.pdf)

From the introduction:

> My main premise is that the two are often conflated, yet the causal
> versus predictive distinction has a large impact on each step of the
> statistical modeling process and on its consequences. Although not
> explicitly stated in the statistics methodology literature, applied
> statisticians instinctively sense that predicting and explaining are
> different. This article aims to fill a critical void: to tackle the
> distinction between explanatory modeling and predictive modeling.

Comment: The link doesn't work. It tends to be better to include a citation, not a link, though in this case, the paper is easy enough to find. Galit Shmueli. "To Explain or to Predict?." Statist. Sci. 25 (3) 289 - 310, August 2010. https://doi.org/10.1214/10-STS330

Comment: @dipetkov Fixed + noted for future.